# Mathematica does not simplify divergent integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I get this as output:

$\frac{1}{6} \int_0^{\infty } 6 t \, dt$

Why it cannot cancel the coefficients?

Comment: Please, provide the code you have used that motivated this question. Latex is not so useful here.

Comment: Strictly speaking the coefficients should cancel only if the integral is well defined.

Comment: Divergence is not necessary here. You have the same behaviour with any integral Mathematica cannot evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know, Mma does not simplify any integrals. However, one can help it. Try the following. Let us first introduce a rule:

```
intRule = 
  Inactivate[Integrate[exprA___ exprB__ , {var_, lim__}], Integrate] /;
     FreeQ[{exprB}, var] :> 
   exprB Inactivate[Integrate[exprA , {var, lim}], Integrate];
```

Here is your integral (inactivated):

```
expr1 = Inactivate[1/6*Integrate[6*t, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}], Integrate]

(* 1/6 Inactive[Integrate][6 t, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]  *)
```

Now

```
expr1 /. intRule

(* Inactive[Integrate][t, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}] *)
```

[image]

Have fun!